# How to view on-line or download my Android Contacts metadata including Linked info from Linked Apps

Tags: applications, contacts, android-device-manager, google-contacts, people-app

There is far more information about my Contacts in my Android phone then what is visible on-line from https://www.google.com/contacts.

Primarily I am referring to the information from "linked contacts" which Android captures and consolidates in the "People" "Phonebook" on the Android OS.

Presumably, Google is capturing and storing this information from my Linked Accounts (the content is not dynamically being pulled from these apps every time I pull up the Phone book).  I would like to view the total information regarding my Contacts on-line including this metadata... anyone know where this may be available?